# Assign "sparse" values to the diagonal of a sparse Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to assign empty or sparse values into a sparse matrix in R. Specifically I want to remove all values in the diagonal of a sparse matrix from the Matrix package.
I am currently only able to assign non-sparse 0's into the diagonal and then remove them with the drop0 function.

Is there a way to assign empty values directly into the diagonal of a sparse matrix?

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
    library(Matrix)
    m       <- Diagonal(10) 
    diag(m) <- 0
    m
    drop0(m)
```

I would like to skip the drop0(m) step.
In my real analysis I have off-diagonal values that I want to keep for a network analysis, so I am not really interested in a empty matrix but a way to assign "sparse" or "empty" values into a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have indeed a matrix of class `ddiMatrix` and want to create an empty matrix:

```
m1 <- as(m, "generalMatrix")
m1@i <- integer(0)
m1@p <- m1@p * 0L
m1@x <- numeric(0)
#10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                         
# [1,] . . . . . . . . . .
# [2,] . . . . . . . . . .
# [3,] . . . . . . . . . .
# [4,] . . . . . . . . . .
# [5,] . . . . . . . . . .
# [6,] . . . . . . . . . .
# [7,] . . . . . . . . . .
# [8,] . . . . . . . . . .
# [9,] . . . . . . . . . .
#[10,] . . . . . . . . . .
```

Of course, you could also simply construct a new empty sparse matrix of these dimensions.

If you have a `CsparseMatrix` with off-diagonal values, coerce it to a `TsparseMatrix` and remove all `i`, `j`, `x` values where i == j (or skip the coercion and calculate the correct indices from `i` and `p` which I find difficult).

```
m1 <- as(m, "generalMatrix")

m2 <- as(m1, "TsparseMatrix")

del <- m2@i == m2@j
m2@i <- m2@i[!del]
m2@j <- m2@j[!del]
m2@x <- m2@x[!del]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see now that my question was unclear. In my current analysis I am not looking for an empty matrix, but a way to remove the matrix of a sparse matrix with off-diagonal values - unlike my example. I have a edited my question.

Comment: See my edit which shows what I'd described. (I'm not sure this is faster than what you have been doing. Do some benchmarking.)